# Azure Sql Basic Plan switched to vCore General Purpose without notice

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

About 10 days ago I created my first Azure Sql Database. I choose the Basic Plan (4.21 €/month). This database is used only for testing purpose. Today I received an email from Microsoft Azure.

Subject of the mail : `Your services were disabled because you reached your spending limit`

Body of the mail : `Keep building in Azure by adjusting your spending limit. Your services were disabled on May 7, 2020 because you’ve reached the monthly Azure spending limit provided by your Visual Studio subscription benefit. To keep using Azure, either:
1.  Wait for your monthly spending limit to reset at the start of next month, or
2.  Adjust your monthly limit for a specific month or for the life of your subscription—you only pay for the extra amount you use each month.`

Why did Azure changed the Pricing Plan of my database without notifying me ? Can some actions cause this ?

I know that I did an `Export Data-tier Application` from Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio from which I was connected to my Azure Database (I made a backup from there). I doubt this explains that.

[image]

[image]

UPDATE

As suggested by NillsF i checked the deployment history and I can confirm I choose the Basic Plan when I created the database (see below). So I still have no clue what's happening to my database.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can check the activity log on your subscription to see who initiated the switch from Basic to Vcore. It seems strange that MSFT would have done this on your behalf.

You can also check the deployment history on your resource group to verify the tier you picked when you created the resource itself:

[image: Check deployments at the resource group]

[image: Check inputs on the deployment to see the tier you selected]

Comment: I updated my question. Maybe I should contact the support of Azure directly ?

Comment: I would. Billing questions are free of charge for support. Did do you see anything in the activity log of your DB?